# Sound automatically switch from USB Speaker to HeadSet

Tags: sound, microphone

Description:    Ubuntu 21.10 / Codename:       impish

Running LXDE if it matters

I watch youtube listening on my external usb speakers and sounds plays just fine.

All of a sudden they go silent and sound is played on the plugged in headset (Plantronics, Inc. DA40 Adapter) without my intervention...

I do see some logs via journalctl near the time of the switch:

```
Mar 01 10:04:57 wilddog pulseaudio[1678]: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write.
Mar 01 10:04:57 wilddog pulseaudio[1678]: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_usb_audio'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Mar 01 10:04:57 wilddog pulseaudio[1678]: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
```

This is a pretty fresh install.

How can I keep it stable on the external speakers?

Comment: Within 4 minutes of a failure, `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` will show log entries, some of which will illuminate the problem. ]

Comment: Sounds like the Plantronics DA40 is periodically waking up and telling the system "I'm a headphone". Can you unplug the DA40?

Comment: @waltinator  I've updated the post....thanks

Comment: Read the error messages. "`Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_usb_audio'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.`" shows you what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bad usb speaker.

Help was sought here:

https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/issues/215